# Extracting numbers following a collection of patterns in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

A lot of stackoverflow questions pertain to extracting numbers following a pattern. However, my task is a bit challenging
I have a list of patterns as follows

```
Customer Id :
C_Id=
CustID=
```

A snapshot of the dataframe is as follows

```
Customer Details                   Purchase Amount
Alpha Customer Id:293                    500
C_ID= 495;task based                     788
Detail PurcCustID=789;982 in k          12345
```

I am looking to get a dataframe as follows

```
Customer Details               Purchase Amount      Customer ID
Alpha Customer Id:293                500                293
C_ID= 495;task based                 788                495
Detail PurcCustID=789;982 in k      12345               789
```

Code Snippet:

```
customer_details = c("Alpha Customer Id:293","C_ID= 495;task 
based","DetailPurcCustID=789;982 in k")

purchase_amount = c(500,788,12345)

customer_data = data.frame(customer_details,purchase_amount)
```

Is there a way to get this done

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(tidyverse)
customer_data %>%
     mutate(CustomerID = as.numeric(str_extract(customer_details, "(?<=I[Dd][:=])\\s*\\d+")))
#               customer_details purchase_amount CustomerID
#1         Alpha Customer Id:293             500        293
#2          C_ID= 495;task based             788        495
#3 DetailPurcCustID=789;982 in k           12345        789
```

---

Or using `sub` from `base R`

```
customer_data$CustomerID <- as.numeric(sub(".*(I(?i)d[:=]\\s*)(\\d+).*", 
                 "\\2", customer_data$customer_details))
```

Comment: Along with Cust ID there are also strings like UserID for which I do not want to do any extraction
would be great if you could provide a solution
for such a situation
where I specify cust/customer/c along with id
so that only numbers succeeding those get extracted

Comment: @PriyankaBasu  Perhaps `as.numeric(sub(".*(C[A-Za-z_ ]*I(?i)d[:=]\\s*)(\\d+).*", "\\2", customer_data$customer_details))`